# Vsphere client 6.0.0.9103891: Index out of range when deploying OVA

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

I'm starting to go crazy. Every time I try to deploy an OVA, my vSphere client crashes with an index out of range error. Others have successfully deployed the same OVA to the same ESX server with the same vSphere client version so the issue has to be isolated to my computer. I've attempted to reinstall vSphere a half dozen times with multiple different versions but all return the same index error. There crash always occurs when selected which Host / Cluster to deploy to. Has anyone seen this issue before and have any suggestions to fix it? My last resort is to just reimage my computer.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Vmomi.HostSystemArray.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at VpxClient.Ovf.OvfUtils.ValidateImport(OvfImporter importer, ComputeResource computeResource, String deploymentOption)
   at VpxClient.VMConfig.NWzHostClusterPage.ValidateData()
   at VpxClientCommon.WizardFramework.TocWzPage.ValidateDataAsync(PageValidationCompletedHandler h)
```

Answer (score 0):

The vSphere Client is outdated and deprecated, it doesn't work very well with modern ESXi versions. Try deploying it via the WebUI, or, if your license allows it, via PowerCLI.